# How do you express the covariant cross product?

Tags: tensors

If the covariant cross product is given by $\mathbf{AxB}= \varepsilon^{ijk}A_{j}B_{k}$, then the Levi-Civita tensor must transform contravariantly for the indices to contract. But according to [this physicsforums thread](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=427853), it obeys the transformation law $\epsilon^{i'j'k'}=|\det (\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x})|\varepsilon^{ijk}$, which means that it transforms neither covariantly nor contravariantly. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross product is not a vector but instead a [pseudovector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector). Furthermore the Levi-Civita "tensor" $\varepsilon$ is not a tensor but instead a [tensor density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!